# Weird CSS issue with absolutely positioned elements

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

In firefox, safari, ie8, the menu system [on my site](http://vanquish.websitewelcome.com/~toberua) works great.

However, in IE7, the link items simply disappear! I've tried many things to see where they may have escaped to, but they have seemed to simply vanish!

[This site](http://www.brunildo.org/test/IE_raf3.html) seemed like it might be onto something, except there are no floats in my header section whatsoever!

Now, I'm usually pretty good with CSS and can get my way out of most IE bugs, but this one is driving me slightly insane.

I've tried using IE8's developer tools too but have not managed to fix it.

Any ideas?

**Note** I realise this site breaks a few usability conventions (the checkbox for one) but I did not design it and don't have much of a say :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is

```
#header ul li {text-indent: -9999px}
```

I can't tell you why other browsers handle it but I tested it and I know it's the problem.

Comment: Must of set that one of a friday afternoon!

Comment: No problem. Well I learnt something as well - IE8's developer tools are actually pretty useable. I put IE8 into compatibility mode then got it to list the styles for a menu element (show styles for click) then disabled with the checkboxes any styles that looked suss - and the answer literal popped onto my screen.

Comment: Ah, it's about time there was something like Firebug for IE. Glad you could learn something too!

Answer (score 0):

What happens in IE7 if you try position: fixed instead of position: absolute?

Comment: If I do that, I won't be able to align absolutely relative of their parent container.